# Is OpenXR plugin supported in World Locking Tools for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, openxr

I'm looking for the best solution to implement Spatial Anchors in my app (Azure Spatial Anchors are not a viable solution for my use-case). I found out about World Locking Tools for Unity, but I'm not sure if it supports Unity 2020.3 using OpenXR plugin or not (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=wlt#choosing-your-world-locking-approach -> this documentation says in that case ARAnchorManager should be used). Can someone please say is this documentation accurate or has support for OpenXR plugin been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLT currently only supports  Legacy XR interface for HoloLens (and initial support for WindowsXR is also available:[Setup for Windows XR Plugin (HoloLens)](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity/DocGen/Documentation/HowTos/XRSDK.html#setup-for-windows-xr-plugin-hololens)). For Unity OpenXR plugin, it is recommended you using the ARAnchorManager.

Comment: Do you maybe know if ARAnchorManager solves the _scale error_ problem described here: [link](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity/DocGen/Documentation/Concepts/Advanced/SpacePins.html#the-problems-to-solve), or WLT is the only solution that does that?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not any solution for this *scale error* of Spatial Anchor. We always recommended rendering anchored holograms within 3 meters of their anchor.